# How to convert archipack object to normal object?

Tags: modeling, archipack-add-on

How to convert archipack object to normal object without parametric dimensions ?
This is urgent for me somebody help

Comment: Hello :). Right click anywhere in the scene should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the outer frame and the object will move to the center, then join.

Goto *Object > Relations > Make Instance Face*

It will create a new copy of the archipack model (window/door), use this model.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.